# Extract Variables From String Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This might be a repeat question but I'm not sure how to look for the answer :P
I'm trying to extract and remove variables from a string.

The string might look like this: `!text (<123456789>=<@$111111111>) (<7654312> = <@$222222222>) ( =<@$3333333333>) Some text that I will need!`

I need the two items in each block?
e.g. `[["123456789", 111111111],['7654312','222222222'],["","3333333333"]]`

Then I need the string exactly but with the variables removed?
e.g. `Some more text that I will need!`

I'm not sure of the best way to do this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to take a look at groups and ranges: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't always have to use regexes, for instance why not write a parser? This gives you much more flexibility. Note that I added `<>` around the  for simplicity, but you could make brackets optional in the parser.

The parser assumes anything that isin't within `()` is free text and captures it as string nodes.

For instance if you wanted only the last text node you could do...

`const endingText = parse(text).filter(t => typeof t === 'string').pop();`

```js
const text = '!text (<123456789>=<@$111111111>) (<7654312> = <@$222222222>) (<> =<@$3333333333>) Some text that I will need!';

console.log(parse(text));

function parse(input) {
  let i = 0, char = input[i], text = [];
  const output = [];
  
  while (char) {
    if (char === '(') {
      if (text.length) output.push(text.join(''));
      output.push(entry());
      text = [];
    } else {
      text.push(char);
      consume();
    }
  }
  
  if (text.length) output.push(text.join(''));
  
  return output;
  
  function entry() {
    match('(');
    const key = value();
    whitespace();
    match('=');
    whitespace();
    const val = value();
    match(')');
    return [key, val];
  }
  
  function value() {
    const val = [];
    match('<');
    while (char && char !== '>') val.push(char), consume();
    match('>');
    return val.join('');
  }
  
  function whitespace() {
    while (/\s/.test(char)) consume();
  }
  
  function consume() {
    return char = input[++i];
  }
  
  function match(expected) {
    if (char !== expected) throw new Error(`Expected '${expected}' at column ${i}.`);
    consume();
  }
}
```